# How to format the result of var dump (array)

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this code, which gets an array from a API URL.

```
                 <?php
                 $url = 'https://api.example.com/v1/w';
                 $data = file_get_contents($url);
                 $data = json_decode($data);
                 echo '<pre>' , var_dump($data->rule->deny_countries) , '</pre>';
                 ?>
```

It displays this:

```
       array(3) {
       [0]=>
       string(2) "US"
       [1]=>
       string(2) "ES"
       [2]=>
       string(2) "MX"
      }
```

How can I only print the values of the strings? ( US, ES, and MX ) that are country codes, and i want to convert them to the full country name, example: United States, Spain, Mexico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print country code with this code:

```
$country_code = $data->rule->deny_countries;
echo $country_code[0]; // print US
echo $country_code[1]; // print ES
// ecc.
```

You can create an array to convert country code to country name like this:

```
$country_name = array("US"=>"United States", "ES"=>"Spain", "MX"=>"Mexico");
```

And then you can print country name with this code

```
echo $country_name[$country_code[0]]; // print United States
echo $country_name[$country_code[1]]; // print Spain
// ecc.
```

Comment: i really appreciate you @Stefino76 its working now
https://panelcws.com/axel/decode.php
Can i add a img before the name of country in the array?

Comment: I want to put the img flag of the country before the name, thank you in advance!

Comment: You can create another array like $img_file = array("US"=>"us.png", "ES"=>"sp.png", "MX"=>"mx.png"); and then echo '<div><img src="'.$img_file[$country_code[1]].'">'.$country_name[$country_code[1]].'</div>';

Comment: @AxelGomez - ...or just call the images `US.png` and so on and do: `src="' . $country_code[0] . '.png"`

Comment: Thank you!! @Stefino76  now working! You are the man!

Comment: Thank you @MagnusEriksson now working!